# (A∖B)×(B∖C)=(A×B)∖(B×C) How to prove?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove that. While I know this is true by thinking about it I'm having a lot of trouble actually writing the proof

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What troubles in writing the proof are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A = \{1,2\}, B = \{1\}$ and $C = \{3\}$. Then $A\setminus B = \{2\}$ and $B\setminus C = \{1\}$. This implies that
$$(A\setminus B) \times (B\setminus C) = \{(2, 1)\}$$
whereas
$$(A\times B)\setminus (B\times C) = \{(1,1), (2,1)\} \setminus \{2,3\} = \{(1,1), (2,1)\}$$
Hence equality is not true.

In order to prove that two sets $A,B$ are equal, you need to prove that $A \subset B$ and $B \subset A$. You do this by letting $x \in A$ be an arbitrary element and showing that it is also an element of $B$ and vice versa, if $y \in B$ is arbitrary, then $y \in A$.

In your statement: the left hand side is definitly a part of the right hand side, but the other inclusion is not true.

Comment: Thank You. It made my understanding a lot easier.